# A regex pattern for specifying characters within a word

Tags: python, regex, integer

Apparently my question was not specific enough. I will add my solution below my original question.

**Question**:
I have character words of three numbers. For example, `001,002,003`. Where there are examples of conversion errors like `Q04` (instead of `004`), I need a regex pattern to identify this kind of error.

Requirements:

- A three number word delimited by space characters that contains at least one capital letter
- the pattern should *not* match `004, 014, 114` type examples
- the maximum value is 200

I am planning to identify these errors in a bunch of text files.

**Additional information** which was left out for clarity (apparently I could have made this clearer)

Test string (only roll entry number 003 is correct. Others `00Q, 0Q2` etc are incorrect and need to be identified as such:

```
text = '00Q ALLAN, Wilham Ross 0Q2 ALLARDYCE, Margaret Isabel 003 ALLARDYCE, Mervyn George Q04 ANKER. Delia Roswyn QQ5 ANKER, Doreen Alison'
```

I ended up using the following Python code with my own regex to identify these mistakes.

```
# matchTestSub.py

import re

def isValidInteger(string):
    try:
        int(string)  # Try to convert the string to an integer
        return True  # If successful, it's a valid integer
    except ValueError:
        return False  # Conversion to integer failed, not a valid integer

text = '00Q ALLAN, Wilham Ross 0Q2 ALLARDYCE, Margaret Isabel 003 ALLARDYCE, Mervyn George Q04 ANKER. Delia Roswyn QQ5 ANKER, Doreen Alison'        

pattern1 = r'\b[A-Z0-9]{3}\b(?![A-Z]+)'
match = re.findall(pattern1,text)
if match:
    for i in range(len(match)):
        x = match[i]
        
        print(x,isValidInteger(x))
```

My regex and test string are [here](https://regex101.com/r/Un6OAd/1)

My thinking for the regex pattern was:

- eliminate other string matches like names using negative lookahead for multiple uppercase chars `(?![A-Z]+)`
- match a 3 char word comprising numerals and/or uppercase

Comment: what do you mean by maximum value is 200. Should it match numbers above 200?

Comment: Unfortunately your pattern does not match '2Q4'

Comment: Could you give some more examples?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. You are correct. I chose a bad example. How about your pattern does not match 1Q4

Comment: also, are the strings always 3 characters long?

Comment: Thank you. Your pattern is good. Yes the numbers are from an electoral roll. Two hundred per page. 000-200

Comment: That pattern also doesn't match `304` or `1000`

Comment: okay try this: https://regex101.com/r/1SU2hj/3

Comment: how long are the strings? ? ?? What is the max length of one

Comment: also which language are you using?

Comment: Any of awk, Perl, Python, Ruby could identify 3 digits as you describe by trying a coversion to a numeral. Then it is easier to test a limited value.

Comment: Providing additional examples would help clarify your question but the main problem is that you have not provided a succinct, complete and unambiguous statement of the question. Also, when addressing comments asking for clarification it's best to edit the question rather than replying with a comment, and when you do edit your question think of it as revising a draft of an article or book. Just tacking on information ("Additional information...) makes the question read like a dog's breakfast. Moreover, there is no need for you to state that you have edited the question...

Comment: ...The only rule is that you cannot materially change the question after an answer has been posted (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Your Python *seems* to be working. The `(?![A-Z]+)` is not needed. What is your question now?

Answer (score 1):

An easy awk that will identify patterns that you describe:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]\n]+"}
($1!=$1+0)||$1>200||length($1)>3{print $1}' file
```

Given:

```
cat file
001 002 003 Q04 250 
006 0Q2 1234 0002
```

Prints:

```
Q04
250
0Q2
1234
0002
```

Or if you want only the qualifying numbers:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]\n]+"}
($1!=$1+0)||$1>200||length($1)>3{next}1' file
```

Prints:

```
001
002
003
006
```

Comment: You shouldn't really vote to close *and* answer a question

Comment: However, I do think the question is worth re-opening after OPs edits

Answer (score 1):

To match *three letter words* delimited by whitespace (or at start/end) that do not contain only letters and from the *three digit numbers* 200 is the maximum number:

```
\b(?<!\S)(?!\D{3}|200|[01]\d\d)[A-Z\d]{3}(?!\S)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HFsVXy/4) (not supposed to match any *4+ letter words* like e.g. `1000`

- `\b` starts with a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (just for efficiency)
- `(?<!\S)` [look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) for not a [non-whitespace](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) (start or whitespace ahead)
- `(?!\D{3}|200|[01]\d\d)` [look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for not three *non-digits* (only letters)
  or if a number (digits only), not in the specified valid range from 0-200
- `[A-Z\d]{3}` matches three uppercase letters and/or digits
- `(?!\S)` not followed by a *non-whitespace* (followed by whitespace or end)

To further match numbers with four or more digits, it can be [easily adjusted (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/6zRtHV/2).

Comment: @Mark this comment was not from OP, have you noticed any OPs comment that mentions numbers with 4+ digits should be matched? It would be easy to adjust though. :)

Comment: ah sorry fair point! I got the white guy names Nick and Dave confused (which is a lot, coming from a Mark lol)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going into a complicated regex that does all, I'd go a simpler way, just a two-steps one-liner:

**Solution**

```
import re
teststring = '00Q ALLAN, Wilham Ross 0Q2 ALLARDYCE, Margaret Isabel 003 ALLARDYCE, Mervyn George Q04 ANKER. Delia Roswyn QQ5 ANKER, Doreen Alison'
[char3 for char3 in re.findall(r'(?<=\b)[\dA-Z]{3}(?=\b)', teststring) if not re.match('\d{3}', char3)]
```

**Result**

```
['00Q', '0Q2', 'Q04', 'QQ5']
```

**How it works**

First pass will check for three characters containing upper cases letters or digits, that are preceeded and followed by word boundaries (\b)

Second pass checks if it's not 3 digits.

The result of the first is pipelined to the second through an array comprehension. This way should be fast overall, without extra array created.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is assert the *word-boundary* with a *positive look-ahead*.
And then, refine the assertion with another *positive look-ahead*, matching the letter *Q* at any position.

```
\b(?=[\dQ]{3})(?=Q..|.Q.|..Q)...
```

Here is an example.

```py
l = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\b(?=[\dQ]{3})(?=Q..|.Q.|..Q)...', s)]
```

Output

```
['00Q', '0Q2', 'Q04', 'QQ5']
```